# Were there any other favors that he requested of you? (of vs. from)

Tags: idiomatic-language

> Were there any other favors that he requested of you?

> Were there any other favors that he requested from you?

'of' version : quoted from United States. Congress. Senate. Select Committee on Improper Activities in the Labor or Management Field · 1957

Which one is correct?

edit: bonus questions

They required an oath of/from me. (of or from?)

He required some more information of/from me. (of or from?)

Comment: In each of your examples, 'of' is more old-fashioned and formal than 'from', but both are correct.

Comment: Certain verbs go with certain prepositions. Did you do any research to see which prepositions go with "request"?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, but grammar changes and I wanted to check them out.

Comment: @BEBYGONES Grammar usually changes very gradually, so if you already know the answer then there's no need to ask here. If you have reason to think that the grammar has changed, please explain why and [show your research](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "*requested of you*" and  "*requested from you*" are grammatically valid. The "of' form I associate with older and more formal language. In fact it brings to my mind the novels of Jane Austen.

To my surprise [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=requested+of+you%2Crequested+from+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows the "of" form to be significantly more common, although the difference is much less marked in the British English corpus. As always when using Google Ngrams one should recall the limits of their sources; they report only expressions found in published books, and they do not distinguish old texts included in currently published books (for example biblical quotes, quotes from Shakespeare, and the like).

In any case both forms are grammatically valid (or "correct") the difference is a matter of style.

As to:

> - They required an oath of me.
> - They required an oath from me.

again both are valid. I would say that the "of" form is more formal, and the difference is a matter of style. I would say much the same of the pair:

> - He required some more information of me.
> - He required some more information from me.

The "of" form seems to me more formal and more old-fashioned, but both are perfectly valid.